# CLT version for $ER_n(p)$ graphs

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-graphs

We defined the Erdôs- Rényi graph as follows:

---

$ER_n(P)$ is the random graph with vertex set $[n]$ where each pair $\{u,v\}$ of vertices is added to the edges set $E$ independently with probability $p$. The law of $ER_n(p)$ is $\mathbb {P}_\lambda$ with probability $\lambda=np$.

We have then a slightly different construction: that gives a coupling of $(\mathbb{P}_{n,p})_{p\in [0,1]}$. Take an i.i.d. family of $(U_e)_{e\in E_2}$ with $U_e\overset{d}{=}\text{Unif}([0,1])$, where $E_2$ is the complete graphe (all edges on $[n]$). Then define the random graph $ER_n(p)$ as having the edge $e\iff U_e\leq p$.

---

I found that the distribution of $X="\text{the number of edges in }E"=\mid E\mid\sim\text{Binomial}(k,2^n,p)$. Now I am trying to solve the following exercise but I don't understand what am I supposed to prove..

---

"Formulate and prove a CLT version for $\mid E\mid$ of $ER_n(p)$ for

- $p$ fixed
- $\lambda$ fixed

(better $p=p_n$, find for which $p_n$ a CLT holds)."

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm confused about the notation Binomial($k, 2^n, p)$. The number of edges in $E$ is Binomial($\binom{n}{2}, p)$ i.e. the number of heads you expect to get if you flip $\binom{n}{2}$ coins of bias $p$. If you fix $p$, you can use the CLT to say something about $|E|$, namely how does Binomial($\binom{n}{2}, p)$ tend towards a Gaussian? If you fix $\lambda = np$, it also tends toward a Gaussian. The question is asking you to prove which Gaussian occurs in which case.

Comment: Oh I see. I assumed that edges were directed, which is false in my case. So I agree about $\text{Binomial}(\binom{n}{2},p)$. So now  I tried the case where $p$ is fixed but I can only conclude that $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}:=\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{\text{Binomial}(\binom{k}{2},p)-\binom{k}{2}p}{\sqrt{n\binom{k}{2}}}}\Rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0,p(1-p))$. But I am not able to express something more about the $\text{Binomial}(\binom{n}{2},p)$ themselves..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bit of overkill but the [Lindeberg-Feller Central Limit Theorem](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~dhunter/asymp/lectures/p93to100.pdf) (for triangular array) gives you the answer rather immediately. The condition that $Var[|E|]={n \choose 2} p_n (1-p_n) \to \infty$ is both a necessary and sufficiently condition that $\frac{|E|-{n \choose 2}p_n}{\sqrt{{n \choose 2}p_n (1-p_n)}}$ converges in distribution to a standard normal.